# what's the difference between [array count] and array.count in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I want to know the size of a NSArray, there are two similar methods I can use like:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"1", @"2"];
NSInteger i = [arr count];
NSInteger j = arr.count;
```

So what the difference between these two methods? Will there be any performance difference or else? Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dot Notation vs Method Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386256/dot-notation-vs-method-notation)

Comment: See these links to know more about this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423853/whats-the-difference-between-dot-syntax-and-square-bracket-syntax   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474284/what-is-preferred-in-objective-c-dot-notation-or-square-bracket-notation

Comment: they are basically the same thing here, both call the _getter_ of the `count` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [arr count]; you send the message count to the array object.

If arr.count comes to the right of some expression, you are calling the getter of the count property, which is basically the same as [arr count];

If object.someProperty comes to the left of some expression, you are calling the setter of the count property, which is basically the same as [object setSomeProperty:someValue].

Because the syntax of the getter and the sending a message to an object represent the same thing for a property (when on right side of an expression), the compiler allows you to use the . (dot) syntax even if the name of what comes right after the dot is not necessarily a getter of a property (for example count is a method of the NSArray class, but compiler does not complain if you use [arr count] or arr.count).

Comment: The last paragraph of your answer doesn't make any sense and isn't correct. Setters and getters are methods on the object that you can call (sending message with). The dotted references are shorthands for sending  messages. The arr.count is either [arr setCount] or [arr count] depending pn whether the reference is on the left hand side of the expression or appears on the right hand side of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

`[arr count]` and `arr.count` are basically the same thing. Both call `obj_msg_send`, the dot syntax is just syntatic sugar for `[arr count]`.

Answer (score -1):

`[arr count]` when you call this you are straight away accessing the getter method.

`arr.count` when you use .(dot) you are accessing the property of an object 
but value wise both gives same count.

Comment: ...and the property can be accessed via its _getter_ only from outside of the class – therefore there is no difference between them at all in this case.

Comment: That s what even i mean. There wont be any difference between both. . Operator will call the getter

Comment: that is not quote straightforward in your answer.

Comment: sorry for tht Editted my ans